# How to set page break on the table with one tr if content of table cell is too big?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 different tables in my div container. I have trouble fitting my last table on the page. In my last table there is only one table cell. The height on this `td` cell is set to `200px`. I'm wondering if I can set `page-break` on my last table. Here is example of my table:

```
<table class="srTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="summary"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    table.srTable {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.srTable th {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #E0DBDD;
}
table.srTable td {
    height: 180px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

@media print {
    table.srTable { page-break-after:auto }
    table.srTable tr { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    table.srTable td { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
}
```

If content in srTable can't fit on the page I would like to see entier table on the next page. Code above didn't work, table stayed on the first page and I couldn't see bottom border of my td cell.

Comment: have you tried `page-break-before` property ?

Comment: @Apolo No, where I should place page-break before? On my table or on tr/td?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a much simpler solution. You only have to set `page-break-inside: avoid;` on the `table.srTable`. The other rules for `<tr>` or `<td>` aren't needed:

```css
table.srTable {
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.srTable th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #E0DBDD;
}
table.srTable td {
  height: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div {
 height:98vh;
}
@media print {
  table.srTable {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<table class="srTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="summary"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```